# RethinkDB Filter for range of dates and times

Tags: date, filter, range, rethinkdb

My database table has the timestamp format "2019-12-08T13:03:16.502639-0600".  I am having difficult figuring out how to filter a 24 hour range of dates so I only get the data plucked from inside that 24 hour running period of time.  I need something like now() then back 24 hours on a running basis.  I have tried several ways but none of them work.

Do I need to parse the timestamp first and only use the parts I need?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the query could look like this:

```
r.table('MyDB').filter(r.row['timestamp'] > r.now() - 24*60*60).run(con)
```